# EditText hint not showing in 5.0.1

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, android-5.0-lollipop, hint

I have the latest 5.0.1 update and the EditText hint has stopped showing:

I have:

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/editTextLocation"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
     android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
     android:layout_weight="80"
     android:clickable="false"
     android:focusable="false"
     android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
     android:hint="@string/chooseLocationHint"
     android:longClickable="false"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:textSize="15sp"
     android:background="@color/white"
     android:lines="1"
/>
```

I've looked through a few "solutions" but they're all quite old and unrelated to 5.0.1

Thanks

Comment: I put your XML in a new scrap project, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to give the hint a colour:

```
android:textColorHint="#000000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough the hint won't display when the EditText doesn't have focus unless the ellipse size is defined (e.g. ellipsize="end")