# EditText Hint not showing

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext

**Nexus 5 Lollipop 5.1.1**

Hint never shows up. Here is my EditText:

```
 <EditText
 android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
 android:background="@android:color/transparent"
 android:hint="@string/feed_message_box_hint"
 android:textColorHint="@color/hint_foreground_material_dark"
 android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
 android:ellipsize="end"
 android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
 android:maxLines="4"
 android:textColor="@color/feed_message_edit_text_font"
 android:textSize="16sp"
 android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
 android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
 android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/feedPictureButton"
 android:minHeight="53dp" />
```

I tried both, and more:

- [EditText hint not showing in 5.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612140/edittext-hint-not-showing-in-5-0-1)
- [EditText hint doesn't show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608234/edittext-hint-doesnt-show)

Any suggestion on why this doesn't show up ?

Comment: Do you tried:

    android:ellipsize="start"

too?

Comment: @AnandSingh Yes.. also nothing..

Comment: which version of your device is???

Comment: @ParthBhayani I wrote it's **Nexus 5 Lollipop 5.1.1**

Comment: i have same problem my edittext not showing in Lollipop 5.1.1, i have a component, everything tried but nothing solved my problem then i set the specific height on Edittext and it showing me on every device. try this @Danpe